# Program stops working by using interrupts

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am learning assembly language in masm. I have read about interrupts and have developed the following code for practice:

```
    INCLUDE IRVINE32.INC
    .data
    plate byte "_"
    counter dword 0
    ppos byte 60
    p byte 15
    .code
    main PROC
    call clrscr
    mov ecx,1000
    mov al, plate
    mov dl, 60
    mov dh, 15
    call gotoxy
    call writechar
    L1:
        mov dh, 0
        mov dl, 0
        call gotoxy
        inc counter
        mov eax, counter
        call writeint
        mov dl, ppos
        mov dh, p
        call gotoxy
        call updateplate
        call writeplate
        mov eax, 2000
        call delay
        loop L1

    exit
    main endp
    writeplate PROC
        mov al, plate
        call writechar
        ret
    writeplate ENDP

    updateplate proc
        mov ah, 01h
        int 16h
        jz quit
        mov ah, 00h
        int 16h
        pressed:
            cmp al, 65
            je left
            cmp al, 97
            je left
            cmp al, 68
            je right
            cmp al, 100
            je right
            left:
                dec ppos
                jmp quit
            right:
                inc ppos
                jmp quit
        quit:

        ret
    updateplate endp
    end main
```

But the problem is every time I run the code the command prompt says the program has stopped working before I could test if the interrupts are working properly. Can somebody help please?

Comment: What is the last instruction executed before it exits?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit-Windows program ("INCLUDE IRVINE32.INC") or a 16-bit-BIOS program ("int 16h")? You cannot mix both! I guess you're using a 64-bit Windows which either don't execute a 16-bit program or don't allow an interrupt access ("int 16").

Comment: Last instruction is int 16h from the updateplate procedure

Comment: uhh... yes I am using 64 bit windows 10! if it doesn't support 16 bit interrupts what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for a key just before exiting. This gives you a chance to see the output screen.

```
  loop L1

  mov ah, 00h
  int 16h

exit
main endp
```